# WPF/Silverlight image/video playlist

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, image, video

I'm somewhat new to WPF/Silverlight so please excuse my ignorance if thw answer is blindingly obvious...

I have the requirement to create a piece of software which gives the user the ability to schedule a playlist of images and videos (possibly flash content too but this isnt essential).

I've had a look at various WPF/Silverlight slideshow apps but none that I've seen so far support a mix of content, they always play either a cycle of images (guess a Storyboard could easily be used for this?) or use Expression Encoder to insert images into a video at placemarks (this is not what I'm after). It would good if there was some way of including transition effects too.

Has anyone seen any examples of anything like this or can you offer any pointers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From XAML point view video is just a XAML element (MediaElement). You can build XAML which switches from Image element to VideoElement and back which will create a transition from Picture to Video.

Answer (score 0):

I think the application I'm working on may be in line with what you're looking for. The mediaElement in WPF can load pictures and video. For transitions I wrote custom HLSL (high level shader language) shader effects to apply the transition while switching between two mediaElements. I hope this helps.

Check it out at: http://hdprogramming.blogspot.com/